# how can I do change color of text when pressed / after that press / again? like comment in visual

Tags: c#

How can I change color of text when pressed / after that press / again? Like comment in visual.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    z++;
    if (e.KeyChar == '/')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor=Color.Green;

        if ((z>1) && (richTextBox1.Text[z - 1] == '/'))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += '/'.ToString();

             while (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Enter)
             {
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
             }
        }
        else
            richTextBox1.Text += '/'.ToString();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtGuid.Text.Contains("//"))
        {
            txtGuid.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

that would work

Answer (score 0):

This probably works

```
 if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.OemBackslash)
    {
      richTextBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
```